# How to stop Hangfire process on IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, aspnetboilerplate, hangfire

I'm using ASP.NET Zero (MVC 5) v5.0.0 with [Hangfire](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire) and everything is working well.

As shown in this [link](https://medium.com/@madhufuture/setting-up-windows-service-with-topshelf-and-hangfire-e29fcf250600), I have setup Hangfire to run as a separate Windows Service.

The problem is, I can't seem to stop the Hangfire process on IIS.

Normally, one can stop it by commenting out this statement:

```
// app.UseHangfireServer();
```

But I can't find the equivalent statement.

**Using ASP.NET Zero template, is there any way to stop Hangfire process on IIS?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's in **Startup.cs** and commented out by default.

Comment: Thanks for your response @aaron , actually I can't find it in Startup.cs ,instead I found this statement `app.UseHangfireDashboard` which responsible of showing dashboard. I think this statment  `app.UseHangfireServer();` is some where in **ABPHangFire** Module

Comment: I need to stop hang fire process on IIS because I've installed it on a separate windows service.  @John

Comment: Which **Startup.cs** are you looking in?

Comment: The one in this path MyCompanyName.AbpZeroTemplate.Web\App_Start\Startup.cs

Comment: Thanks for your effort @aaron, so in MVC5 version is there an solution?